# Beginner python set intersection error

Tags: python, list, set, intersection

```
rare = (["word1","word4","word5"])
freq = (["word1","word2","word3"])
unique = rare.intersection(freq)
print unique
```

error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'intersection'

Am I not creating the sets correctly?  They look like the examples in documentation -- but I can't seem to use normal set methods on them.

What is the proper syntax for creating sets if these are lists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This way you're not creating sets, just regular lists. Use the `set` function:

```
rare = set(["word1","word4","word5"])
freq = set(["word1","word2","word3"])
```

Maybe you're confusing sets with tuples. A tuple is created with expressions between parenthesis, but you must provide at least a comma:

```
("this", "is", "a", "tuple")
("anotherone",)
```

Tuples are like immutable lists, but they're not sets.

Comment: Thank you, that was driving me frickin' crazy.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you're using a recent Python, see also Tavian Barnes' answer, since it's more concise.

Answer (score 4):

On Python 2.7+, this is syntax for intersections using [set operators:](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html#set-objects)

```
>>> rare = {"word1", "word4", "word5"}
>>> freq = {"word1", "word2", "word3"}
>>> rare & freq
{'word1'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want this:

```
rare = {"word1", "word4", "word5"}
freq = {"word1", "word2", "word3"}
unique = rare.intersection(freq)
print(unique)
```

Note that the syntax for set literals has been backported as far as Python 2.7.

Comment: @JoelCornett: Why not? It compiles fine, it executes fine, it does what the OP wants.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I think it depends on Python version. For instance, 2.5 doesn't accept it, 2.7 does.

Answer (score 1):

```
unique = set(rare).intersection(freq)
print(unique)
```

Comment: That's a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

u can do it like that its shorter i guess :

```
rare = (["word1","word4","word5"])
freq = (["word1","word2","word3"])
unique = set(rare).intersection(set(freq))
print(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution had an issue because both 'rare' and 'freq' objects were arrays. They must be converted to a **set** data type. I use '&' rather than 'intersection' as it seems neater.

```
unique = set(rare) & set(freq)
print(unique)
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
unique = set(rare).intersection(freq)
print(len(unique))
```